# GCC implementation for behavior of reinterpret cast

Tags: c++, gcc, reinterpret-cast

How can I know how will reinterpret cast work on GCC compiler? Is it mentioned in the documentation? May I know any reference or link if it exist?

Comment: I believe `reinterpret_cast`'s behavior is defined by standard and not by specific implementation. What exactly do you want to know about it?

Comment: It is not specific to compiler it works the same whether it is a GCC compiler or VS compiler .It is defined by the C++ standard and the compilers cannot change the behavior of it.

Comment: He wants to know about GCC, not the standard.

Comment: @Pubby: OP's question asks about `reinterpret_cast<>`'s behavior, not its implementation.  The behavior is specified by the standard and cannot be changed by the compiler.  How it is implemented will likely depend on the compiler and target hardware.

Comment: What? There's a lot of implementation-defined behaviour in the standard. `reinterpret_cast` is one of the features with implementation-defined behaviour in it. *The standard explicit allows the implementation to define some of its behaviour*.

Comment: The behavior of many uses of `reinterpret_cast` is undefined.

Comment: @James: But the semantics of it are well-defined, for uses for which they are defined ;)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal:  Yes.  Your tautology is tautological.  o_O

Comment: For example: If I cast a pointer to integer, in standard it is mentioned "The mapping performed by reinterpret_cast is implementation-defined" so do i have to look up how mapping is performed by the compiler?

Comment: Yes. "Implementation defined" specifically means that the Standard does not specify what should happen, but a conforming implementation (compiler, etc.) will select a specific behaviour _and document (define) it_.

Comment: As for GCC, regrettably I can't find info, including @the usual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Implementation.html (which unless specified, covers `g++` too)... but `reinterpret_cast` _seems_ simply to reinterpret underlying  _object representation_ (series of `unsigned char`) as the new type - much as one would intuitively expect, and as cppreference claims: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast Nonetheless I hope this _is_ documented somewhere. Fwiw, when punning by `union`, another common impl-def 'reinterpret' method, GCC does document using object representation

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation in the standard it is very explicit about different types. But for the basic pointer we have:

> A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined. [ **Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. — end note** ] A value of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to an integral type; the conversion has the same meaning and validity as a conversion of (void*)0 to the integral type. [Note: A reinterpret_cast cannot be used to convert a value of any type to the type std::nullptr_t. — end note ]

For integers:

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined. [Note: Except as described in 3.7.4.3, the result of such a conversion will not be a safely-derived pointer value. —endnote]

Comment: @Loki.Astari: What does it basically means to know the addressing structure of the underlying machine?

Comment: Assuming you us a normal machine it means the address in memory (it is worded like that so that exotic machine that do not have memory (example dataflow) are still compatible with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `reinterpret_cast` many times with g++. In embedded programming, it's useful for mapping a `struct` that represents a peripheral's registers to its (fixed) address:

```
struct DEV_Registers
{
volatile uint32_t REGA;
volatile uint32_t REGB;
// ...
};

static DEV_Registers& DEV(*reinterpret_cast<DEV_Registers>(0x40000000));
```

This lets me write code like:

```
DEV.REGB = 0x12345678;
```

which does the right thing (set the register at 0x40000004 to the value 0x12345678) and is quite legible.

It's hard to tell if your question is asking for details beyond this.

Comment: The question was asking for a statement from GCC about this, not an anecdote ;-) but since no such statement seems to exist - leaving us to assume GCC silently follows the "intended to be unsurprising" clause by simply reinterpreting per-byte "object representation" - your anecdote becomes rather useful! Fwiw, I observe the same, e.g. with regard to `reinterpret_cast`ing `[unsigned] char *` buffers to `SomeStruct` (probably the least risky implementation-defined cast, seeing as the converse is defined). Incorporating a set address is an extra trick, though! I've not got that low-level yet ;-)

Comment: I wish I had better than anecdote, but if they're expecting a response from the GCC developers proper, they're asking in the wrong place. A better place would be the [GCC mail lists](http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html), though I can't tell from a cursory glance which one is best suited for this question. And yes, there are some unholy things you have to do in the low-level world that are still better than an `asm` block.

Comment: unholy, or just _incredibly_ useful! I work with so many arcane gadgets that C++ is a miracle. Correct me if I'm wrong: I don't think any other language offers such low-level addressability and yet high-level semantics. This is mostly portable if careful - and that's precisely because I can write handler classes/templates to guarantee bit/byte order, etc. Rarely must I stray into the world of implementation-defined behaviour, but if I do, it's good that GCC mostly works intuitively! whether specifically documented or not... ;-)

Comment: Actually, in C++11 (GCC 4.7 and later) I can do things that are super easy to read and still compile down to the same or smaller code than code using nothing but `#define`s. For example, I can define an I/O pin that drives an LED as `typedef OutputPin<'B', 0, Initially::High, Active::Low> LED0Pin;` which describes PIO port B bit 0 as an output pin, reset to high (+VDD), and active low (GND = LED on). Since it's a type, it consumes no code space by itself.

Comment: Then code initializes the pin with `PIO::Setup<LED0Pin>();` which sets all the PIO registers as needed and drives output high. To turn on the LED, I just write `LED0Pin::Assert();`, and to turn it off I just write `LED0Pin::Release();`. If, later, I discover that the LED was actually active high, I just change the typedef to have `Initially::Low, Active::High` instead, and no other changes are needed. And all this "fluff" compiles down to single operations thanks to inlining and `constexpr`.

Comment: Great examples, and not all that far from my own set of templates! :-) Yup, by using templates cleverly, I get the same tailored and machine-optimised code as I used to get in C by monotonously typing endless piles of `multiBitReg_otherBits_theseThingsAreUnrelated &= ~maskOutWhatIDontWant; ditto |= maskInWhatIDoWant; repeat(100);`. Given how many fussy old devices I work with, it's hard to overstate how incredible an upgrade this was for me. Now the compiler generates the code for me - there's an idea!